# Joining product attributes table with the product table to display product

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I have three tables for listing products with product attributes

**Product Table** with dummy data

[image]

[image]

**Product_Attributes** with dummy data

[image]

[image]

**Attributes** with dummy data

[image]

[image]

Kespersky antivirus (productid = 1) has no attributes but the iPhone (productid =2) has two attributes applicable to it, memory and resolution both in **Attribute** table which has its value stored in **Product_Attribute**  table.

How do I join these tables to show/display both the products with there corresponding attributes?

**EDIT**

I need to display these products as

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the result you require for this dummy data so we can see the format you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik, sure. Give me a few minutes and I'll edit my question.

Comment: Use proper reporting tools instead of forcing SQL to display data the way you want!

Comment: @DakshB Can you look at my answer below?  It works for any number of attributes and returns  the results in the format you have given above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will work for any number of attributes:

```
select product.productId, product.name,
group_concat(concat(attr.attributeName, ":", pa.attributeValue))
from product
left outer join product_attributes pa 
on (pa.productId = product.productId)
left outer join attributes attr 
on (attr.attributeId = pa.attributeId)
group by product.productId, product.name
```

Comment: This will not create separate colums.

Comment: @PhilipDevine  Seems to me that this produces exactly the result as requested: "How do I join these tables to show/display both the products with there corresponding attributes?"  And it works for any number of attributes, which none of the other answers accomplish

Comment: @danb, ill look into it. am just a bit tied up for 2-3 days.

Answer (score 4):

Your question requires a pivot, which needs to be predefined. Meaning, if you want to include 2 extra COLUMNS in your result set, your query can then only store up to 2 attributes. This is a PRESENTATION layer problem, not query layer. But alas, I have a general solution for you. It assumes you will have a max number of 2 attributes (for the reasons states above). Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
  P.ProductName,
  A.AttributeName,
  PA.AttributeValue,
  B.AttributeName,
  PB.AttributeValue
FROM lb_products P
LEFT JOIN (select row_number() over (partition by productID order by AttributeID asc) rn, * 
           from lb_product_attributes x) PA
  ON P.ProductID = PA.ProductID and PA.rn = 1
LEFT JOIN (select row_number() over (partition by productID order by AttributeID asc) rn, * 
           from lb_product_attributes x) PB
  ON P.ProductID = PB.ProductID and PB.rn = 2
LEFT JOIN lb_attributes A
  ON PA.AttributeID = A.AttributeID
LEFT JOIN lb_attributes B
  ON PB.AttributeID = B.AttributeID;
```

And the SQL Fiddle for you to play around. Good luck! And feel free to ask any questions :)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49a9e0/5

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
  P.ProductName,
  P.Price,
  -- Add other Column Here
  A.AttributeName,
  PA.AttributeValue
FROM Product P
LEFT JOIN Product_Attributes PA
  ON P.ProductID = PA.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Attributes A
  ON PA.AttributeID = A.AttributeID
```

**Output**

```
ProductName   Price    AttbituteName    AttributeValue
Kaspersky     380      NULL             NULL   
IPHONE        45000    Memory           64 gb
IPHONE        45000    Resolution       21500 pi
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please have look again.

Comment: Are Memory and Resolution column Name?

Comment: did you mean memory and resolution?

Comment: both memory and resolution are values/record which I inserted after creating the table.

Comment: Yes, I know those are record of Attributes Table. By the way, in which way you want your result, Test#1 or Test#2. http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/20T2

Comment: the above result is what I am exactly looking for. Kespersky antivirus doesn't have any of those two attributes which the iPhone has. So, when a user clicks kespersky to view details, I need it to show exactly the same but when he clicks iphone I need it to show the extra attribute (memory and resolution) that the iPhone has.

Comment: I see TEST 2 very close to what I need but can we not have Memory = Null and Resolution = Null displayed for kespersky antivirus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80453/discussion-between-daksh-b-and-mahedi-sabuj).

Comment: I think you are having trouble with presentation not only query, you need to choose test two, where you are trying to show that result, when you talk about view details option?, web aplications, desktop, mobile, etc. let us know more detail.

Comment: You cant have a result with many rows, with diferent columns... .

Answer (score 2):

[Philip's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2166594/philip-devine) answer is certainly good, and he spells out the problem in that you need to define a static number of attributes if you're doing a pivot. I'm not sure the windowed functions are necessary, though, so here's how I'd do it:

```
select
  prd.productId
  ,max(case when lpa.attributeId = 1 then attributeName else null end) attributeName1
  ,max(case when lpa.attributeId = 1 then attributeValue else null end) attributeValue1
  ,max(case when lpa.attributeId = 2 then attributeName else null end) attributeName2
  ,max(case when lpa.attributeId = 2 then attributeValue else null end) attributeValu2
from
  lb_products prd
  left outer join lb_product_attributes lpa on lpa.productId = prd.productId
  left outer join lb_attributes atr on atr.attributeId = lpa.attributeId
group by
  prd.productId
```

Comment: The window function is necessary because we aren't guaranteed what the attribute ID's are.  At least not in the definition.  We just need "the first two".

Comment: Really? The presence of the `lb_attributes` table seems to belie that. The display at the bottom of the question references specific attributes, which have specific `attributeId` values in the dimension. I don't see any mention of "the first two" in the question.